# How can I use these modules together?

Tags: 7, mimemail

Is it possible to use [Mimemail](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail/), [Mail System](http://drupal.org/project/mailsystem), and [SMTP Authentication Support](http://drupal.org/project/smtp/) modules together?

Currently I am using Mimemail to send HTML-formatted messages; however, because of the configuration of my server, these e-mails are often being recognized as spam.  To reduce the chance that they will be recognized as spam, I want to use the SMTP Authentication Support module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. We can use the Mimemail + SMTP Authentication Support. Plz check the link http://drupal.org/node/1200142 and check the part : Alternative Approach: Mail System + SMTP + Mime Mail

Comment: tl;dr, after enabling the [mailsystem](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem), [mimemail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail), and [smtp](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) modules, go to `admin/config/system/mailsystem` in your site and scroll down to the "New Class" fieldset. Create a new class using `MimeMailSystem` for `format()` and `SmtpMailSystem` for `mail()`. Use that newly created class for the "Site-wide default MailSystemInterface class". Also make sure to appropriately configure your SMTP settings at `admin/config/system/smtp`.

Comment: @thirdender thank you so much for posting the summary. This solves it!

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/node/1200142 is a good way to set up Drupal + Mimemail + SMTP.
It needs also Mail system module (as a dependency of Mimemail).

There is a trick:
When using the Mime mail__SMTP bridge for both *Site-wide default MailSystemInterface class* and *Mime Mail module class* is OK when sending email without inline images (I didn't try with attachments).

But when trying to make Mailmime embed images, it results in a PHP Mailer (Drupal) error saying "Mail body empty".

To make the system work,you have to set *Site-wide default MailSystemInterface class* to MimeMailSystem.

I'm not sure this is a reliable way because it could mean you are not using SMTP connection at all.
Though, when you run a SMTP test from SMTP module configuration page, it works as expected and when checking received mail headers, it confirms the use of SMTP.

Edit:
My bad, send mails with such settings is not using SMTP at all, but it uses drupal default mail system.

I'll open a new question for my needs.