# Mimemail + SMTP + Mail System: inline images make body empty

Tags: media, emails, nodes

I'm trying to send HTML mails on a Drupal 7 install.
For this, I use Mail System, SMTP authentication and Mime mail modules.
I used settings as Alternative approach on this page http://drupal.org/node/1200142

The mail content is built within custom modules I'm writing (not by rules or simplenews, I mean).
I tweaked default Mail mime template to my needs, within a separate, light drupal theme.

My mails are sent (and received) without error when they contain only HTML and styles.
There are no error also when I had images with absolute url: Mime mail is leaving them as such.

I need to embed a few small images within my mails and when I try to do so, accordingly to what's written in Mime Mail README, I get a "Message body empty" at the top of my page when my code tried to send the mail.

I placed `dpm($message)` along the Mime mail code to locate where the body content is left empty.
I finally reached the 
`class MimeMailSystem implements MailSystemInterface` 
located in `mimemail/includes/mimemail.mail.inc`

Body content was still there.

Then the `class MimeMailSystem__SmtpMailSystem implements MailSystemInterface` 
in `default/files/mailsystem/MimeMailSystem__SmtpMailSystem.mail.inc`

Again, my content was still there, along with inline BASE64 encoded images.
So the content disappears somewhere after that (in Mail System ?)

As I pointed it out [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39474/how-can-i-use-the-mimemail-with-stmp-authentication-support-modules-together-on/168098#168098), switching `Site-wide default MailSystemInterface class` in Mail System settings from 
`MimeMailSystem__SmtpMailSystem` 
to
`MimeMailSystem`
allows the mail to be sent with its images, but the mail is no more sent through SMTP.

I'm pretty sure this is not due to a bug within one of the 3 modules, but I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

The only thing I doubt from here is how I build the mail content :

- I build some variable HTML content
- I store it in `$message['body'][]` in my module's `hook_mail` implementation
- then I print `$body` in my `mimemail-message.tpl.php` within static HTML part of the mail

The images I try to embed are in public files. I tried to link them :

- with relative paths like `sites/default/files/<filename>`
- with relative paths like `public://<filename>`

with no success.

Does anyone has a magical one character solution for something I missed ? ;)

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Further investigations lost me into the [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module
It's complicated enough and I couldn't locate something to help me find what was the problem coming form my configuration.

After a quick search within [issues of Mime mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/mimemail?status=All&categories=All), someone was linking to another module to handle SMTP connection: [enter link description here](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpmailer)

Basically it works the same way than SMTP Authentication support but its benefit is you don't have to create a bridge mail system class between it and Mime mail, it's natively integrating with Mime mail.

To make it work properly, I had to configure Mail system as such :

- Site-wide default MailSystemInterface class: MimeMailSystem
- Mime Mail module class: MimeMailSystem
- PHPMailer module class: DrupalPHPMailer

and in Mime mail settings :
 - set Mail engine to PHPmailer